# How to use Azure Vault Secret for the configuration provider in your function APP?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, environment-variables, azure-keyvault

I am trying to store all my configurations in the Azure Keyvault Secret and want to use like function app configuration.

I have added the secretes into the Azure Key Vaults and able to read through `GetSection` or `GetValue` methods, however for SignalR, it is trying to get the configuration value of `AzureSignalRConnectionString` for negotiation. It can be solved if I declared that variable into the local json configuration however for upper environments like stage/prod this type of configuration will not be there. So, need to use the secret from keyvault.

Comment: Did you follow this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: @silent - I have gone through the below article and solved it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in the “Configure” method of the “Startup” class of your function app –

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri("Azure Key Vault URL"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
    var config = configBuilder.Build();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);
}
```

It would easily retrieve the environment variables in the function app declared in the Azure Vault Secret.